# SQL Separarlo en Columnas

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo esta consulta:

```
select SUBSTRING(                                                                   
    (select stuff( (select CAST(',' AS varchar(MAX)) + RTRIM(LTRIM( isnull( CM_VH_TableroCampanaDetalle.Descripcion, CM_VH_TableroCampanaDetalle.Descripcion)))
    from CM_VH_TableroCampanaDetalle
    where CM_VH_TableroCampanaDetalle.IdTablero = 168
    for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) , 1, 800)  AS ComposicionCampana
```

Que me arroja esto:

```
ComposicionCamapana
Radio touchscreen (AVH-A2150BT), Cámara de retroceso, Sensor de retroceso
```

Lo que quiero es separarlo en columnas así:

```
ComposicionCamapana
Radio touchscreen (AVH-A2150BT)
Cámara de retroceso
Sensor de retroceso
```

Necesito ayudaa!

Comment: Quieres decir que quieres que lo arroje en distintas filas en una sola columna?

Comment: asiii es!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides, según tus datos de muestra y contrario a tu descripción, lo único que necesitas es simplificar la consulta.

```
SELECT LTRIM( tcd.Descripcion) AS ComposicionCamapana
FROM   CM_VH_TableroCampanaDetalle AS tcd
WHERE  tcd.IdTablero = 168;
```